# Рендер таблиц на javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый день.

Задача: нужно отрендерить строки всех таблиц на странице с помощью javascript. Четные одного цвета, не четные другого.

Вопрос: есть ли какой-нибудь скрипт для данной задачи?

P/S: Желательно jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   (function ($) {
    $.fn.tableRowStyle = function(options){
     var options = $.extend({
      classEven: 'tr-even',
      //класс для не четных строк, можно задать любой 
            classOdd: 'tr-odd',
      //класс для четных строк, можно задать любой 
            classHeader: 'thead',
      //класс для заголовков, можно задать любой 
            classHover: 'tr-hover',
      //класс для подсветки принаведении, можно задать любой 
      classSelected: 'selected',
      //класс для выбранной строки, можно задать любой 
      multiSelected: 'true'
      //'false' означает возможность выделить только одну строку
      //'true' означает возможность выделить любые строки
      //'none' отключить возможность выделения строки
     },options);
     return this.each(function() {
      var current = $(this);
      current.find('tr:has("td")').hover( //выбираем из всех элементов td, которые имеют внутри td (обычные ячейки)
          function (){
                       $(this).addClass(options.classHover);
                      }, 
                            function () {
                             $(this).removeClass(options.classHover);
                            }//навешиваем событие hover, первая функция при наведении курсора, вторая возвращает внешний вид при уходе курсора
                  ).click(function(){
          var row = $(this);
          if(options.multiSelected=='false'){// проверяем какой параметр задан
           if(row.parent().find('tr').hasClass(options.classSelected)){row.removeClass(options.classSelected)}
           else{row.addClass(options.classSelected)}
           //манипуляции для выделения только одной строки
          } else if(options.multiSelected=='true'){
           if(row.hasClass(options.classSelected)){row.removeClass(options.classSelected)}
           else{row.addClass(options.classSelected)}
           //манипуляции для выделения всех строк
          } else {return false}
          // возвращаем false, если не хотим вообще ничего выделять на клик
         });
         //Назначаем классы сперва четным строкам, затем не четным, а потом выделяем все заголовки
      current.find('tr:even').addClass(options.classEven);
            current.find('tr:odd').addClass(options.classOdd);           
            current.find('tr:has("th")').removeClass(options.classEven).addClass(options.classHeader          
     });

};
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Не проверял с ходу, но идею беру Вашу. Спасибо, Вам плюс и верный ответ!)